# Pressure of 2 immiscible liquids of diffrent density in a u tube

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure, fluid-statics

2 diffrent liquids in a u shaped tube can have height difference at equilibrium but when I try to analyse the pressure at the same level of c,on the surface of more denser liquid there is only atmospheric pressure but on the other hand the less denser liquid have both the atmospheric pressure and the pressure due to the column of liquid above it,so they are not same but they must be.where am I getting wrong? [image]

Answer (score 1):

> so they are not same but they must be.where am I getting wrong?

[image: Pressure]

Why '*must they be the same*'?

We can ignore the part below $A$ and $B$ in the semi-circular part of the tube.

Now, to have equilibrium (no movement) we must have the following balance of forces:

$$|CB|A\rho_R g=(|AC|+|CD|)A\rho_L g$$

Or:

$$|CB|\rho_R=(|AC|+|CD|)\rho_L$$

The pressure at the left hand point $C$ is given by Pascal's Law:

$$p_C=p_0+\rho_L g |CD|$$

So these pressures don't have to be same and they aren't.

Answer (score 0):

For liquid to not move/remain in equilibrium net force should be balanced ALONG A LINE for example in case of hydraulic press you have very high force on one side and very low on the other side but still they remain in equilibrium because the pressure along a line remains the same and hence the force (here you take any cylindrical part at the base of the tube of very low crossection so that pressure can be treated as constant you will see it) here in this case also you do the same thing and the forces will balance out .I know this is not very intuitive but that's  how we can see it by seeing the forces acting on the different arms and comparing them both will give you the incorrect intuition